# Single plot through several columns

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with several columns, let's say, 200. I would like to plot something like

`plot 'datafile.dat matrix w image`

but using only the even columns in the datafile. I guess that there should be a way combining `using` and `every`, but I did not find anything useful yet.

As suggested already in the answers, something like `plot "test.dat" every 2 matrix w image` should work. Nevertheless, if I have the data

```
1   -1  2   -2
3   -3  4   -4
5   -5  6   -6
7   -7  8   -8
```

and I use `plot "test.dat" every 2 matrix w image`, what I get is
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km4W6.png)

I am using gnuplot 5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04.

Many thanks.

Comment: `help plot for` should get you going

Comment: This would help when plotting several lines or images in the same plot, but I only need one single image.

Comment: Why don't you simply play around with `every` and read it's doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data that looks like

```
1   -1  2   -2
3   -3  4   -4
5   -5  6   -6
7   -7  8   -8
```

then you can draw an image of just the odd columns by

```
plot "test.dat" every 2 matrix w image
```

[image]

Note that all the values are positive, and that the image is upside down. If you want the even columns use

```
plot "test.dat" every 2::1 matrix w image
```

This works because the `matrix` keyword effectively transforms the data into a three-column (x,y,z) format.

### Update

There was a bug in some early versions of the gnuplot 5.0 series that caused the behavior you see, see [this report](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1835/). This has been fixed in patchlevel 5 (i.e., gnuplot 5.0.5) and later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I tried already, but for some reason, using the exact same data as in your example I get something different (see the edited question).

Comment: That is very strange... is that in a new gnuplot session? Do change any default settings in a `~/.gnuplot` file? For me this works both using gnuplot 5.2.1 on MacOS and gnuplot 4.6.2 on linux.

Comment: I am using gnuplot 5.0 in linux and I tested in terminal qt and x11. This behaviour remains even if no default settings are changed in the `.gnuplot` file and the session is new...I agree it looks like there is something wrong going on here.

Comment: Which pathlevel of gnuplot 5.0 are you using? The release notes to patchlevel 5 (gnuplot 5.0.5) mention "FIX various bugs affecting matrix data plotted "with image"...

Comment: It sounds like you are running into [Bug 1835](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1835/) which has been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I just updated my version of gnuplot and this made the trick. If you edit your answer with the information regarding this bug I will mark it as good!